# Best app to edit text in PDF files on OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have tried Wondershare PDF editor to edit text in PDF files; it works but not so well. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Is this for editing pre-existing .PDF files, or for creating them? I think @Adam gave what would probably be the best answer. Google's [Drive](http://drive.google.com) may suffice for simple tasks, with Illustrator, or InDesign probably being best for anything requiring significant design layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, if you can stomach the investment, go with apps from the Adobe suite.  I'm a graphic designer and I find it easier to use InDesign and Illustrator than those other less established apps.  If you have a little bit of time to learn them, they're pretty easy to use for basic tasks.